# Return Latest Sorted Date from Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I currently have this schema

```
var dataSchema = new Schema({
hid: { type: String },
sensors: [{
    nid: { type: String },
    sid: { type: String },
    data: {
        param1: { type: String },
        param2: { type: String },
        data: { type: String }
    },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}],
actuators: [{
    nid: { type: String },
    aid: { type: String },
    control_id: { type: String },
    data: {
        param1: { type: String },
        param2: { type: String },
        data: { type: String }
    },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}],
status: [{
    nid: {type: String},
    status_code: {type: String},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}],
updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
created: { type: Date }
});
```

And the query that I'm trying to build should search the schema by "hid" and then only pick the last object (by date) from the "sensors", "actuators" and "status" arrays but I can't figure out how to do that.

With this query I can partially achieve what I'm trying to get but it only give me one array at the time so I have to query the database three times and I would avoid doing so

```
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([
                    { $match : { hid : "testhid" } },
                    {$project : {"sensors" : 1}},
                    {$unwind : "$sensors"},
                    {$sort : {"sensors.date" : -1}},
                    {$limit : 1}
                ])
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can you please post sample data (test documents)

Comment: Do you want to sort it not only by sensors date but also on the others dates? You can unwind multiple times but not one time multiple arrays. This should work in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best advice here would be to "store" the arrays as sorted in the first place. Chances are that they probably already are considering that any [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operation ( or even if you used `.push()` ) will actually just "append" to the array so that the latest item is "last" anyway.

So unless you are actually "changing" the `"date"` properties after you create, then the "latest date" is **always** the "last" item anyway. In which case, just [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) the entries:

```
Data.find({ "hid": "testhid" }).select({
    "sensors": { "$slice": -1 },
    "actuators": { "$slice": -1 },
    "status": { "$slice": -1 }
}).exec(function(err,data) {

]);
```

"If", some reason you actually did manage to store in a different way or altered the `"date"` properties so they latest is no longer the "last", then it's probably a good idea to have all future updates use the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier with [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/). This can "ensure" that additions to the array are consistently sorted. You can even modify the whole collection in one simple statement:

```
Date.update(
    {},
    {
      "$push": {
          "sensors": { "$each": [], "$sort": { "date": 1 } },
          "actuators": { "$each": [], "$sort": { "date": 1 } },
          "status": { "$each": [], "$sort": { "date": 1 } }
      }
    },
    { "multi": true },
    function(err,num) {

    }
)
```

In that one statement, every document in the collection is having every array mentioned re-sorted to that the "latest date" is the "last" entry for each array. This then means that the above usage of `$slice` is perfectly fine.

---

Now "If", absolutely none of that is possible for your case and you actually have some reason why the array entries are not to be commonly stored in `"date"` order, then ( and only really then ) should you resort to using `.aggregate()` in order to the the results:

```
Data.aggregate(
 [
   { "$match": { "hid": "testhid" } },
   { "$unwind": "$sensors" },
   { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "sensors.date": -1 } },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "sensors": { "$first": "$sensors" },
       "actuators": { "$first": "$actuators" },
       "status": { "$first": "$status" },
       "updated": { "$first": "$updated" },
       "created": { "$first": "$created" }
   }},
   { "$unwind": "$actuators" },
   { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "actuators.date": -1 } },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "sensors": { "$first": "$sensors" },
       "actuators": { "$first": "$actuators" },
       "status": { "$first": "$status" },
       "updated": { "$first": "$updated" },
       "created": { "$first": "$created" }
   }},
   { "$unwind": "$status" },
   { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "status.date": -1 } },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "sensors": { "$first": "$sensors" },
       "actuators": { "$first": "$actuators" },
       "status": { "$first": "$status" },
       "updated": { "$first": "$updated" },
       "created": { "$first": "$created" }
   }}
 ],
 function(err,data) {

 }
)
```

The reality there is that MongoDB has no way to "inline sort" array content in a return from any query or aggregation pipeline statement. You can only really do this by processing with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) then using [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and finally a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) using [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) to effectively get the single item from the sorted array.

This you need to do "per" array, since the process of `$unwind` is creating seperate documents for each array item. You "could" do it all in one go like:

```
Data.aggregate(
 [
   { "$match": { "hid": "testhid" } },
   { "$unwind": "$sensors" },
   { "$unwind": "$actuators" },
   { "$unwind": "$status" }
   { "$sort": { 
       "_id": 1, 
       "sensors.date": -1,
       "actuators.date": -1,
       "actuators.status": -1
   }},
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "sensors": { "$first": "$sensors" },
       "actuators": { "$first": "$actuators" },
       "status": { "$first": "$status" },
       "updated": { "$first": "$updated" },
       "created": { "$first": "$created" }
   }}
 ],
 function(err,data) {

 }
)
```

But it's really not that much improvement on the other process with all things considered.

---

The **real** lesson here should be to *"keep the array sorted"* and then doing an operation to `$slice` the last item is a very simple process.

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete answer

Comment: One last question, is there a way to also include a `$elemMatch: { nid: "1"}` when slicing the `sensors` array? I tryed this `"sensors": [{$elemMatch: { nid: "1"}}, {"$slice": -10 }],` but it does not work. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @danielebuso That requires the aggregation framework. It is not possible for projection to match any more than 1 array element anyway. But there is a simpler way using the aggregation framework. **But** that is another question, and should be asked seperately.